# Why is Mr Norrell so anxious to keep Mrs Pole's fate a secret?

Tags: tv, jonathan-strange-and-mr-norrell

I have been enjoying the BBC adaptation of Jonathan Strange & Mr Norrell. I am not familiar with the book.

However, a key part of the plot that I don't understand is the desperation of Mr Norrell to keep some of his actions secret.

> Specifically, I'm puzzled as to why he goes to such extreme lengths to hide what's happened to Mrs Pole. Why he seems so afraid that anyone should find out about the "Gentleman with Thistledown Hair" and how he's twisted the bargain made to restore her to life?

The only thing I can think of is that he considers it "uncouth" magic, not in keeping with his desire to restore magic to a "respectable" position in society. But if that were true, it seems unlikely non-magicians would have the requisite knowledge to appreciate that what he's done is not "respectable"?

I know the story has been seriously truncated in the TV adaptation. Is it perhaps further elucidated upon in the original text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dealing with fairies is the wild magic, the unrespectable magic of the Raven King. For Norrell to reveal that he, himself, has turned to that source for the resurrection of Lady Pole would undercut his position from the start. He wants his idea of 'respectable English magic' to be commonly accepted by the public as well as other magicians. Remember, he is a very vain man.

Answer (score 3):

Norrell is a magician who studies only the known magic and the magic that is written in the books (of magic). He thinks the fairy magic is unstable and it has consequences a magician cannot comply. When you cast a spell by the help of a fairy, there is always something you haven't thought about and the fairy takes advantage of that. And Norrell knows this can be dangerous.

*Also*, inside, he thinks he is better than the magicians who have practised fairy magic. He wants to prove that magic can work without the fairies. And he thinks he proved this when he demonstrated a complicated magic spell that animated the statues in the church.

*As a result*, when people questioned his knowledge and power he used fairy magic to beat death. But he was the victim of his own thoughts in the end. The fairy tricked him into a deal that cost Mrs. Pole's sanity (for a while). This is the reason why he wanted to avoid that topic and tried to keep the entire thing as a secret.

Hope this helps!